# How to create a list based in a p:selectOneRadio

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page with the following selectOneRadio definition:

```
<p:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px">
   <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" layout="custom"  required="true" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Número de Documento" itemValue="0" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nombre(s)" itemValue="1" />                     
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Estado" itemValue="2" />   
   </p:selectOneRadio>

   <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <p:radioButton for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" />
              <h:outputLabel for="txtNroDocumento" value="Número de Documento" />
              <p:inputText id="txtNroDocumento" value="#{empleadoMb.empleado.nroDocumento}"/>

              <p:radioButton id="txtNombre" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" />
              <h:outputLabel for="txtNombre" value="Nombre(s)" />
              <p:inputText />

              <p:radioButton id="txtEstado" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2" />
              <h:outputLabel for="txtEstado" value="Estado" />
              <h:selectOneMenu value="#{empleadoMb.busqueda}">
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue="-1"/>
                 <f:selectItems value="#{empleadoMb.listaEstado}" var="st" itemValue="#{st.idParametro}" itemLabel="#{st.dato}"/>                                
              </h:selectOneMenu>
   </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
```

The controller is a ManagedBean. What I need to know is how can I create a list of employees based on it's idcard, name or status when I select one radiobutton.
I've been improvising in my backing bean but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your selectOneRadio needs a value and ajax and your selectOneMenu an id:

```
<p:selectOneRadio "#{empleadoMb.radioValue}" id="customRadio" layout="custom"  required="true" >
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Número de Documento" itemValue="0" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nombre(s)" itemValue="1" />                     
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Estado" itemValue="2" />  
     <p:ajax listener="#{empleadoMb.radioValueChanged()}" update="selectMenu" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{empleadoMb.busqueda}">
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar" itemValue="-1"/>
             <f:selectItems value="#{empleadoMb.listaEstado}" var="st" itemValue="#{st.idParametro}" itemLabel="#{st.dato}"/>                                
          </h:selectOneMenu>
```

In your bean you can handle your list in the listener then:

```
private int radioValue;

public void radioValueChanged(){
// your current value is in the variable radioValue now, you can change your list depending on the value here, the update in the p:ajax will refresh the selectOneMenu after that.
}

//getter + setter for radioValue
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to express that I need to get the inputs from every radiobutton (one for 'Número Documento'/'Nombre'/'Estado'). Then I got: 
`<p:commandButton value="Buscar" icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{empleadoMb.getListaEmpleados}" update="table-wrapper"/>`. This button updates a table and find a list based on one criterion ( 'Número Documento'/'Nombre'/'Estado') selected from the radiobuttons. What I really need is to get those inputs. Or if you have a better idea, feel free to teach me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If your commandButton is in the same form as the inputs it should submit their values to the bean, so you should be able to work with the values of the inputfields in your getListaEmpleados method. If that doesn't help create a mcve which involves the parts of your bean and the page which are related to the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: By now I just need to know how can I get those values from every radiobutton. I mean I just need to set one of those values in a variable, then I'll use that variable to find and create list's. Logycally I know how to, but I need to know how can I do that in my jsf/htmlx page. Thanks for your time and your answer.

Comment: You just need to set a value for each of your inputs like you already did for one inputText:   <p:inputText id="txtNroDocumento" value="#{empleadoMb.empleado.nroDocumento}"/>